# php flourish fActiveRecord store store two times

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, orm, flourishlib

i´m using flourish for my database tasks in my php application.
Now i have the problem that the store method saves new datasets always severel times in the database.

```
$o1 = new Version();
$o1->setVersion(rand(1, 99999));
$o1->save();
var_dump($o1);
```

I get the linked output from the var_dump. http://pastebin.de/128872

Version is a child class from BaseModel, BaseModel is a child-class from fActiveRecord.

There is my method save():

```
        public function save($forceCascade = false) {
            if (parent::getCreatedAt() === null) 
                parent::setCreatedAt(time());
            parent::setLastModifiedAt(time());

            parent::store($forceCascade);
        }

        public function setCreatedAt() { return false; }
        public function setLastModifiedAt() { return false; }
        public function setId() { return false; }
        public function store($force_cascade=false) { return false; }
```

Could someone help or does know if there are unfixed issues? Ive seen that flourish is not longer programmed...
(Sorry for bad english :/ )

EDIT:
Ive founded out that my browser call every page two times... i dont know why.
So this problem is solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found the issue / fail.
If im using "view_source" from chrome it is calling the page two times. So my model was called twice and saved twice.